# Display another button and print even numbers when button pressed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is my code below I am not able to add a second button in it. I have somehow managed to create one button and how can display set of even numbers when a button is pressed

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Example2 extends JFrame {

public Example2() {
        initUI();
    }

public final void initUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setToolTipText("A Panel container");

        JButton button = new JButton("Even");
        button.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
        button.setToolTipText("A button component");

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Odd");
        button2.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
        button2.setToolTipText("A button component");



        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button2);

        setTitle("Tooltip");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Example2 ex = new Example2();
                ex.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: What did you try before you got stuck?

Comment: Add ActionListeners to your JButtons to get them to have some functionality. You can learn how to do that here: [How to use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Comment: Thanks to all mates who helped me but I figured out my mistake the code is correct and working the only mistake is that both buttons has the same set bounds values so the other button was visible but underneath the present one, I thank all of you helping thank you alot.

Answer (score 3):

Ditch the `null` layout and use a real `LayoutManager` and both your buttons will appear in the layout. 
Consult the [Swing layout manager tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for some sample code

Answer (score 2):

Some fixes you can try:

1. Put the `getContentPane().add(panel)` part after you add the buttons to the panel.

You should also start off by defining a list or array of even numbers that you want to display, along with a JTextArea or JTextField or another means of displaying the text. For those components, just use the `setText(String string)` method.