# My whole code is complete but I am not able to add a second button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

Please take a look at my code it is working fine the way I want but the only issue is that I want to add another button opposite my current button and I am not able to do so can any body please help me.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example2 extends JFrame {

public Example2() {
        initUI();
    }

public final void initUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setToolTipText("A Panel container");

        JButton button = new JButton("Even");
        button.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
        button.setToolTipText("A button component");

        JButton button2 = new JButton("Odd");
        button2.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
        button2.setToolTipText("A button component");

        //Add action listener to button
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent  e)
                    {
                        //Execute when button is pressed
                        System .out.println("You clicked the button");
                        int sum=0;
                                for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){
                                    if(i%2==0){
                                        System.out.println(i);
                                        sum+=i;
                                    }
                                }
        System.out.println("Sum of even numbers: "+sum);
                    }
        });

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button2);

        setTitle("Tooltip");
        setSize(500, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                Example2 ex = new Example2();
                ex.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display another button and print even numbers when button pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961713/display-another-button-and-print-even-numbers-when-button-pressed)

Answer (score 7):

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

That is where it starts to go wrong.

1. Use layouts.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) & [Effective Layout Management: Short Course](http://www.cs.buu.ac.th/~seree/lecture/AWTLayoutMgr/shortcourse.html) for more details.
2. Use:

   - The appropriate layouts.
   - Possibly [nested inside one another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).
   - With appropriate layout padding and component border/insets for white space.

---

As an aside.

```
    ...
    button.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
    button.setToolTipText("A button component");

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Odd");
    button2.setBounds(100, 60, 100, 30);
    ...
```

Did you notice how the bounds of the two buttons were identical?  What do you *think* happens when you put two components of the same size in the same place?

Comment: I m not able to do it can you help

Comment: @user1054393 For useful links see  my answer.

Comment: 2 separate 'one line fixes' were provided by fkr, but also go through the links in the answers of @Sanjay & me.

Comment: How ironic. This is exactly what was recommended in [his other question with the same snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961713/display-another-button-and-print-even-numbers-when-button-pressed)

Comment: @Robin (sigh)  You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink.

Comment: @AndrewThompson correct. +1 for your remark about the bounds. I skipped the rest of the code when I saw the `null` layout and started writing my answer

Comment: @Robin *"I skipped the rest of the code when I saw the `null` layout"*  I got bored, and came **back** to it.  Actually I was interested to see how it looked on-screen to guess how it was *supposed* to be laid out, but gave up when I realized there were two buttons in the exact same place!

Comment: You got bored when you saw two buttons?

Answer (score 3):

You have to change `panel.setLayout(null)` to layout you need. For example:

```
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

or

```
    panel.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.CENTER));
```

Answer (score 3):

Andrew Thompson +1 ,

Here are some usefull links :

1. [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
2. [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)
3. [Adding space between components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336139/977676)

Comment: That last one was a good answer, but missed one technique for adding white space, layout padding.  E.G. `new GridLayout(0,3,10,10); // Use 10px padding`  Because I can't up-vote the other answer (again) I'll just up-vote this one.  BTW - thanks for the comment re links, I knew there was an edit open that I should have put through.  ;)